# Ubuntu install not allowing me to install or modify sda partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm trying to install Xubuntu 18.04LTS on an old hp dv6 laptop. I'm using a live cd and I would like to Legacy install to my hd sda which should have plenty of space.
[sda drive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/db63P.jpg)

The NTFS paritions are related to an old windows 7 OS.

The install recognizes the drive is there but it only allows me to install to sdc. sdc is my usb drive.
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frAUj.jpg)

I know that I need to create a boot, swap, /, partition, but because of the issue described above I cannot create a new partition table with sda because it is not an option.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the disk controller set to RAID in your BIOS? re: " I need to create a boot, swap, /, partition"... no, don't manually create these partitions yourself. Let the Ubuntu installer create a standard configuration on its own.

Comment: @heynnema I don't see RAID in the BIOS. I don't see an option to specify disk controller.

Comment: Is there a setting for HDD drive settings?

Comment: @heynnema  Please see bios here. I do not see any options. [link](https://imgur.com/a/GsMWg4y)

Comment: Your BIOS is version F.09. Go to the HP web site and check if there's a newer BIOS.

Comment: Is wiping the entire sda an option?